# Group stored procedures in oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, group-concatenation

We are writing tons of oracle stored procedures to handle our business logic. We would like to do a physical grouping for better maintenance and understanding.

I can see package is helpful for encapsulation and logical grouping... Is there anyway we can create namespace physically to group certain procedures based on business logic.

Please advice us on this...

Comment: What is the best way to write and manage packages when you have loads of procedure to achieve certain functionality...Every functionality of my application covers 100 to 150 stored procedures because of the complex business logic... What are all the best practices to keep it efficient,simple and maintainable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you have business logic that relates to how you process data in the DB. That data is likely to be table based and the tables are likely to be per business entity.

For example, there might be a table that holds details of customer accounts. Therefore all business logic pertaining to creating, maintaining, validating, listing, etc. of customer accounts would exist in the package PKG_ACCOUNTS.

Without knowing how granular or generic your procedures are trying to be its hard to see how you would need something more that that. That sort of approach, with packages covering logic that can apply to multiple objects, has always worked very well for me.

Perhaps some examples would help if you don't see that this is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks @BriteSponge.... I think packages covering logic is the best way for my requirements... In this way we wont disturb the other functionality during changes